# IntelliJ, unable to run catalina.sh

Tags: intellij-idea, osx-mountain-lion, catalina

I'm running on a mac, 10.8.2.

Starting this morning, I am unable to start my tomcat 6.0.18 in debugger mode.

```
"Error running MediaPlanner: Cannot run program "/Volumes/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/bin/catalina.sh" (in directory "/Volumes/work/apache-tomcat-6.0.18/bin"): error=1, Operation not permitted
```

I've made sure I have permissions on this file and all files in the tomcat directory (recursively). 
I've made sure the files are not in apples quarantine list (gatekeeper).
I've tried switching to tomcat 7.x.
I've installed java 1.6.0_37-b06-434.jdk since i was using an older verison of 6.
this has been a stable setup for about a year.

I recently ran the java update that apple pushed out via updates (not sure if it matters).

This morning IntelliJ pushed out an update to 11.1.4. I installed it without error.

I am able to use terminal to manually run `catalina.sh`.
I've lost a day of work trying to get this to work. I've scoured this site and others trying everything I find.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install 11.1.4 update with a patch? Does it help if you install it again from the .dmg?

Comment: It upgraded inside IntelliJ while it was running

Comment: Does it help if you install it from the .dmg available at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html? Your settings will be preserved.

Comment: I re-downloaded it and it kept my settings.   same error :(

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the disk image that I keep all of these files in was itself marked as quarantine.

This file has been around for years.  so while I can't explains why it was suddenly marked as quarantine (and all the files inside of it)  that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change permission:

```
chmod -R 777 apache-tomcat-8.5.8
```

(I use macOS Sierra 10.12.1, Apache Tomcat 8.5.8. In general, other versions of Mac OS or Apache Tomcat will be the same.)